# ER Model Diagram Good design? how to express myself?

Tags: entity-relationship

I am trying to understand the concept of ER modelling, but I do not yet succeed. I have designed the ER model about movie database, but I do not know wheather it is a good design and how to connect the entities:

1. between Actor and Film i want to say "actor can play in each film only once" and at the same time "many actors can play in many movies" -- is it 1 to 1 relation or many to many?

and HOW do we need to think about entities ans relations between them? relations to one user, one film, one actor, one director, or in general?

**UPDATE: new question** : should the relation between `Director` and `Film` be 1 to many or many to many? I want to say : "one director can have many films && many directors can have may films" ??

[image]

Comment: Translating the field names to English would help...

Comment: @bgp, sorry, done. i have changed the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this:  There are many movies.  There are many actors.   It makes sense that you would only want to include each actor in a particular movie once, but otherwise you want to be able to "mix and match" the movies and actors to express the relationship.

Looking at your diagram, you don't seem to have any fields which express the relationship between Film and Actor - those lines need to match actual fields.  Read up on foreign keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

The relationship between Actor and Movie that you want is actually many-to-many.  You can express this with a "join table" (you'd need to add this to your diagram).

Something like this would work:

```
FilmActor
-------
uidFilm
uidActor
```

And put a unique constraint on those two fields together so it can't be duplicated (i.e. the same Actor can't appear in a Film twice)

Comment: it seems I do not have any other relations...such as a film can have a rating, and a registered user can have favourite films etc. do I need to add an attribute "favourite film" to the user entity or should create some "join table"?

Comment: should the relation between Director and Film be 1 to many or many to many? I want to say : "one director can have many films && many directors can have may films" ?

Comment: @Oleksandra I did answer your original question in detail.  Not sure why you unaccepted it.